# count registrations in conferences where the registration type price > 0

Tags: laravel

I have a query to count the number of registrations in a confernece:

```
    $registrationsCount = $conference->registrations->count();
```

But I want to get only the registrations in conferences that are associated with registration types which price is > 0. Do you know how to achieve that? For example if the conference "test conference" has two registration types "rt1 and rt2", the price of rt1 is 0 and the price of the rt2 is 10 and there are 5 registrations in the registration type "rt2" the query should return 5, because there are 5 paid registrations in the conference.

Conference model:

```
 public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }
```

Registration model:

```
 public function registration_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_registration_types');
    }


public function conference(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
}
```

Registration Type model:

```
   public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

public function registrations(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Registration', 'registration_registration_types');
    }
```

Participants model:

```
public function registration(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
}


public function registration_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
}
```

tables structure:

```
conferences: id, name
registrations: id, status, conference_id, user_that_did_registration
registration_types: id, name, price, conference_id 
participants: id, registration_id, registration_type_id, name
```

Comment: add $conference getting methods

Comment: Thanks, but I didnt understand which methods? The $conference is an object like "Conference {#289 ▼ #fillable: array:19 [▶]
  #dates: array:2 [▶] #appends: array:1 [▶] #connection: "mysql" #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id" #keyType: "int"+incrementing: true
  #with: [] #withCount: []  #perPage: 15+exists: true +wasRecentlyCreated: false #attributes: array:22 [▶]  #original: array:22 [▶ #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}".

Comment: $registrationsCount = $conference->registrations->where('price', '>', 0)->count();

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that the price column is in the registration_types table not in the registrations table.

Comment: With "        $registrationsCount = $conference->registrations->registrationTypes->where('price', '>', 0)->count();
" shows "Property [registrationTypes] does not exist on this collection instance.
".

Comment: That error becouse $conference->registrations is instance of **\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::**

Comment: Thanks, but why "$conference->registrations->where('price', '>', 0)->count();" dont shows that error? It also ues "$conference->registrations".

Comment: see my answer  !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
$count = Registration::whereHas('registration_types', function($q) use($user) {
                            $q->where('price ', '>', 0);
                        })
                    ->where('conference_id', $conferenceId)
                    ->count();
```

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears ""SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.registration_registration_types' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `registrations` where exists (select * from `registration_types` inner join `registration_registration_types` on `registration_types`.`id` = `registration_registration_types`.`registration_type_id` where `registrations`.`id` = `registration_registration_types`.`registration_id` and `price ` > 0) and `conference_id` = 1) ◀"
".

Comment: Do you have a table named `registration_registration_types` ?

Comment: No, only "registrations" and other "registration_types".

Comment: Maybe the issue is that in the Registration model there is this relationship "public function registration_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_registration_types');
    }".

Comment: And in the RegistrationType model this "public function registrations(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Registration', 'registration_registration_types');
    }".

Comment: But changing to only registration_types it shows "Not unique table/alias: 'registration_types' (SQL: select `conferences`.*, (select count(*) from `registrations` where `conferences`.`id` = `registrations`.`conference_id` and exists (select * from `registration_types` inner join `registration_types` on `registration_types`.`id` = `registration_types`.`registration_type_id` where `registrations`.`id` = `registration_types`.`registration_id` and `price` > 0)) as `registrations_count` from `conferences`)".

Comment: No you have to create that table, because in manyToMany you have to create a pivot tavle !

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I didn't fully understand your request, but I see the following two possibilities:

```
Conference::whereHas('registrationTypes', function ($query) {
        $query->where('price', '>', 0);
    })
    ->withCount('registrations')
    ->get();

// will give you something like this
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Laracon",
    "registrations_count": 100
  }
]
```

or alternatively, you could perform the price check within the count

```
Conference::withCount(['registrations' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('registration_types', function ($query) {
            $query->where('price', '>', 0);
        });
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, with "Conference::withCount.." it shows "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.registration_registration_types' doesn't exist (SQL: select `conferences`.*, (select count(*) from `registrations` where `conferences`.`id` = `registrations`.`conference_id` and exists (select * from `registration_types` inner join `registration_registration_types` on `registration_types`.`id` = `registration_registration_types`.`registration_type_id` where `registrations`.`id` = `registration_registration_types`.`registration_id` and `price` > 0)) as `registrations_count` from `conferences`)".

Comment: The "Conference::withHas" returns a collection of conferences "Collection {#294 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Conference {#283 ▶}
  ]
}". But it should return the number of registrations in conferences in which the registration type price is >0. For example if the conference "test conference" has two registration types "rt1 and rt2", the price of rt1 is 0 and of the rt2 is 10 and there are 5 registrations in the registration type "rt2" it should return 5, because there are 5 paid registrations in the conference.

Comment: Your relationship definition seems to be wrong, you are referencing a non-existent table. Please fix it.

Comment: And about your second comment: In this case, use the second query. As stated, I wasn't too sure what you are actually looking for because you did not give all details in your question and to be fair, your words oculd be interpreted in multiple ways. But after your explanation, go for query 2. ;)

Comment: Thanks but the relationships seems correct. In the error appears "registration_registration_types.registration_type_id" there is no "registration_registration_types" table, there is a "registrations" and a "registration_types" table, I dont know if that can be the issue.

Comment: Then you have weird relationship definitions on your models. And your request just got even more weird, because now only query 1 would technically work, but probably not do what you want. So yeah, I'm totally confused now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$conference->registrations->sum(function ($registration) {
    $registrationTypes = $registration->registration_types->where('price', '>', 0);
    return $registrationTypes ? $registrationTypes->count() : 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears "Call to a member function where() on null
".

Comment: This performs the `where` in-memory and is quite memory costly.

Comment: Thanks, but still appear "Call to a member function where() on null
".

Comment: Also fox **registrationTypes to registration_types**

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears ""SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.registration_registration_types' doesn't exist (SQL: select `registration_types`.*, `registration_registration_types`.`registration_id` as `pivot_registration_id`, `registration_registration_types`.`registration_type_id` as `pivot_registration_type_id` from `registration_types` inner join `registration_registration_types` on `registration_types`.`id` = `registration_registration_types`.`registration_type_id` where `registration_registration_types`.`registration_id` = 1) ◀"
".